# How to get latest binary version from Archive using Powershell

Tags: docker, powershell

I need a *PowerShell script* to get *latest binary version from this archive list* https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/

So as when I run the script, it checks for latest zip and returns me latest version number and link to download. For example, if latest file is **docker-24.0.6.zip** then I need

- 24.0.6
- link to that zip which ultimately I can use to download

I have subsequent script to utilize that zip but I have never tried getting it from an archive url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

docker-check.ps1:

```
$archiveUrl = "https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/"

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $archiveUrl

$pattern = '<a href="([^"]*docker-([\d.]+)\.zip)"'
$matches = [regex]::Matches($response.Content, $pattern)

$latestVersion = $null
$latestDownloadLink = $null

foreach ($match in $matches) {
    $downloadLink = $match.Groups[1].Value
    $version = $match.Groups[2].Value

    if ($latestVersion -eq $null -or [Version]$version -gt [Version]$latestVersion) {
        $latestVersion = $version
        $latestDownloadLink = $downloadLink
    }
}

if ($latestVersion -ne $null -and $latestDownloadLink -ne $null) {
    Write-Host "Latest Version: $latestVersion"
    Write-Host "Download Link: $archiveUrl$latestDownloadLink"
} else {
    Write-Host "Unable to find the latest version and download link."
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Omer. Btw I faced one issue with this script - *Invoke-WebRequest : The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available, or Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing parameter and try again.* So I had to add -UseBasicParsing parameter with Invoke-WebRequest to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

To offer a simpler alternative to [Ömer Sezer's helpful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77236383/45375), based on the observation that the version list at https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/ is simply being appended to, implying that the most recent recent version is listed *last*:

```
$rootUrl = 'https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/'

# Get the name of the ZIP file containing the latest version, 
# assumed to be the last one ([-1]) listed.
$latestVersionZipFile = 
  [regex]::Matches(
    (Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing $rootUrl), 
    '\bdocker-(.+?)\.zip'
  ).Value[-1]

# Construct the full download URL
$latestVersionZipFileUrl = $rootUrl + $latestVersionZip
```

<sup>Note: `-UseBasicParsing`, which prevents parsing of the response by the obsolete Internet Explorer engine, is only required in *Windows PowerShell* - you can omit the parameter in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).</sup>

You can then download the latest version as follows:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing $latestVersionZipFileUrl -OutFile $latestVersionZipFile
```

---

If you don't want to rely on the *last* ZIP file listed being the most recent one, replace the `$latestZipFile = ...` statement with the following, which sorts the extracted filenames by their embedded version number and picks the highest one.

```
$latestVersionZipFile = 
  [regex]::Matches(
    (Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing $rootUrl), 
    '\bdocker-(.+?)\.zip'
  ).Value |
  Sort-Object { [version] ($_ -replace '^docker-|(-ce)?\.zip') } |
  Select-Object -Last 1
```